# ClickOnce doesn't create StartMenu entry and shortcut on Windows 7 x64

Tags: visual-studio-2008, clickonce, windows-7-x64

I've application that I deploy to share with [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce) so other users can install it and use it on their own machines. It worked fine till I noticed that when I install this application on my own machine (Windows 7 x64) it doesn't add a start menu item (even though it installs correctly, and I have it in Control Panel / Programs). I didn't have that problem when my development machine was Windows XP. The application also deploys fine on other Windows XP computers.

Also during installation (when I rerun setup) even though I already have [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) Framework 3.5 it always wants to install one (it starts that and terminates a few seconds later - probably the installer sees that it's already there). I can run application straight from a share; it is just a bit of a pain to do it.

Are there some special settings I should do? Or some patches?

I have [Visual Studio 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2008) and system with all optional updates installed. The application is written in [C#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29) and uses .NET 3.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have SP1 installed for Visual Studio 2008 and .NET 3.5?

What is the target CPU of your deployment -- is it "Any CPU" or 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: Are the files actually installed under the ClickOnce cache? c:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\obfuscatedfolder\obfuscatedfolder\ ? Can you find the folder with the actual exe in it? If you double-click on it does it run? Have you tried installing it by calling the .application file directly instead of setup.exe (by now you surely have the prerequisites installed, which is what setup.exe does), like \\myshare\myfolder\myapp.application ?

Comment: I can run application from share. It's no problem. Just that it never creates anything in my system (full admin rights with UAC off). I found the folder inside the path you suggested but .exe in it acted like it was the non-deployed version.

Comment: You can run it from the file share that it's deployed to? How are you doing that? With a URL, like \\share\folder\setup.exe or \\share\folder\myappname.application? 
What do you mean by "it never creates anything in my system" -- if you find the folder inside the path I suggested, that IS the ClickOnce deployment. Where else are you expecting to see the files?

Comment: Another question -- do you have the Publisher Name and Product Name filled in in the Options dialog that comes up when you click Options in the publish tab for the project properties? The Publisher Name is what shows up as the folder on the Start Menu, and the Product Name is the name of the shortcut that it puts in that folder.

Comment: I didn't had that. For some reason it disappeared. Don't know how thou. It works now! Gracias, i lost hope!

Comment: I wish i could vote this 5 times ;) Please update your answer for future reference that PublisherName and ProductName are required and maybe sum our comments up. Thanks Again!

Answer (score 0):

Publisher name and Product name in the Publish tab of the project properties must be populated in order for the shortcut to appear on the Start Menu.